# Jquery, check if two values of dynamically created textboxes are equal

Tags: jquery, textbox

I'm having a bad time trying to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

I'm dynamically generating pairs of textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="pass1[1]"><input type="text" name="pass2[1]">
<input type="text" name="pass1[2]"><input type="text" name="pass2[2]">
<input type="text" name="pass1[3]"><input type="text" name="pass2[3]">
```

Now I'm trying to dynamically check if pass1[n] and pass2[n] have the same value. I managed to do it only in one pair of them and knowing exactly it's name. See the code I've used:

```
var $pass1 = $("input[name^='pass1']");
$pass1.data("value", $pass1.val());

var $pass2 = $("input[name^='pass2']");
$pass2.data("value", $pass2.val());

setInterval(function() {
    var data1 = $pass1.data("value"),
        val1 = $pass1.val();

    var data2 = $pass2.data("value"),
        val2 = $pass2.val();


    if (data2 !== val2 || data1 !== val1) {
        if (val1 === val2 && val1 != ""){
          alert("changed");
       }
        $pass2.data("value", val2);
        $pass1.data("value", val1);
    }
}, 100);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WB8E/1/) when the input value changes check if the corresponding pair (based on the current input index) is equal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var compareTo = index % 2 ? index-1:index+1;

        alert($(this).val()==$('input').eq(compareTo).val());

    });
});
```